# Pivot Table in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to create a Pivot Table into VBA but when I run the code I’m getting an error.
I would like my Pivot table to contain 2 data:

- On the first column (lines): Mandat
- On the 2nd column (values):  montant RI

The code is below. Thanks for your help !

```
Sub TCD_MANDAT()

    '
    ' 
    ' Etiquette de ligne : Mandat -> 1ere colonne
    ' En valeur : montants RI -> 2ème colonne
    '
    
    'Source and Target
    Dim TableSource As Worksheet
    Set TableSource = Application.Workbooks("OP TEFAL AUTOMATIQUE.xlsm").Worksheets(2)
    
    Dim TableTarget As Worksheet
    Set TableTarget = Application.Workbooks("OP TEFAL AUTOMATIQUE.xlsm").Worksheets(4)
    
      
    Dim rangeSource As Range
    Set rangeSource = TableSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim rangeTarget As Range
    Set rangeTarget = TableTarget.Range("A1")
    
    'Decla variable
    Dim tcd1 As PivotTable, tcdCache As PivotCache

    Set tcdCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=rangeSource)

    'Creation pivot table from cache
    Set tcd1 = tcdCache.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:=TableTarget, _
        TableName:="TCD 1")
        
        
    'Création des étiquettes et valeurs
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TCD 1").PivotFields("Mandat")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TCD 1").PivotFields("Montant RI")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message and what line throws it?

Comment: The object model for pivot tables is a monster. Recommend just recording a macro and tweaking the resulting code to suit your needs & make it safe.

Comment: @BigBen - I’m getting an "Invalid qualifier" error at the line :
Set rangeSource = TableSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Comment: `Dim tableSource As Worksheet`, `Set tableSource = Application.Workbooks(...`. Same for `tableTarget`.

Comment: I'm guessing `TableDestination:=TableTarget` is going to blow up too.  Try `TableDestination:=rangeTarget`.

Comment: I edit and this part is working now :) - Now I have an "Invalid procedure call or argument" error at the line : Set tcd1 = tcdCache.CreatePivotTable( …..

Comment: Did you change to `TableDestination:=rangeTarget`?

Comment: Yes, it's working now ! Thank you @BigBen ! :D